# pgAdmin view list of indexes

Tags: pgadmin

This seems like such a simple question that I feel I have to be overlooking something, but alas here I am since I couldn't find someone else asking this on the internet...

How do you view a list of indexes in pgAdmin?

I know I can select a table, and then view that tables indexes... But what I want (and I guess what I'm used to coming from the world of Oracle and TOAD) is to be able to quickly view ALL my indexes.  (I know I can write an SQL, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of a GUI?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*List Indexes using pg_indexes view. (from google):*

> The pg_indexes view allows you to access useful information on each index in the PostgreSQL database. The pg_indexes view consists of five columns: schemaname: stores the name of the schema that contains tables and indexes.

For me a UI does not replace SQL-statements. 
I am working with SQL Management Studio and Oracle Enterprise Manager in my company and there are a lot of information I use SQL queries for. From my perspective the UI supports you in doing the most common tasks, and you can surely do a lot more of stuff on DB level.

Answer (score 4):

to get the table description including the index right click on the table and get create script  result will show all indexes  created on a table

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not complete. Almost 2 years later. Primary Key only it seems.
In any case other tools such as DataGrip show them. If it is a service hosted on a major provider they are also shown.

We discovered this as Azure identifies duplicate indexes but we had to dig deep to find them, and in fact they were not absolutely identical but unique trumped non-unique. This was an inherited state.

It will probably be fleshed out in due time.

Answer (score 0):

So, pgAdmin could certainly make this easier to do.  However, if you /insist/ on the GUI you can:

- go to Schemas->public->Tables, right-click, select Search Objects.
- from the dropdown on the top-right select Indexes
- then it wants you to 'Type at least three characters' into the search box...
- ...so type %%%   (Hah! the wildcard, tricked you, GUI)

Now the caveats:

- you don't get indices which are for primary keys
- you don't get indices which are for constraints
- [any others I don't know about???]

Of course you could separately select Primary Key and Unique Constraint from the dropdown and repeat, but at that point you probably better off just going to the GUI's Query Tool and entering:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

...or...

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes
WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog'
```

With all the other bells and whistles pgAdmin has, I don't know why there's not an easier way.  I'm totally fine with just the per-table view, FWIW, but if you go to Tables->[table_name] and right-click to select Indices, it also skips pkey and constraint ones, which I find misleading.  Of course they're right above under the menu list-item Constraints.  Just gotta remember to check there before you create a new index that duplicates an existing constraint index -- which pgAdmin will let you do!